# Testing with gmail account

Tags: testing, gmail, google-schemas

I try to test schema integration with rails application. I used my personal Gmail account to configure SMTP :

    `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
        port:                 587,
        domain:               'gmail.com',
        user_name:            'XXXX@gmail.com',
        password:             'XXXX',
        authentication:       'plain',
        enable_starttls_auto: true

    }`

I test to send it to my own account. But it's seems that doesn't work..

I test with example code from :

PS : The mail pass validation

Thank you

EDIT : Header of my mail

    `Return-Path: <XXX@gmail.com>
    Received: from gmail.com (84-74-24-22.dclient.hispeed.ch. [84.74.24.22])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id m8sm9364668eeg.11.2014.04.23.13.34.35
    for <XXX@gmail.com>
    (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Wed, 23 Apr 2014 13:34:35 -0700 (PDT)
    Date: Wed, 23 Apr 2014 22:34:34 +0200
    From: XXX@gmail.com
    To: XXX@gmail.com
    Message-ID: <535823da92e7c_3d223ffc2442dbe093598@WS-39.local.mail>
    Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Merci_d'avoir_command=C3=A9_!?=
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="--==_mimepart_535823da916a1_3d223ffc2442dbe0934a9";
    charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`

Comment: You should add the email headers so that we can take a look

Comment: Header added to my post

Comment: There are no SPF/DKIM headers, without those Gmail doesn't process the microdata (check https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en#).

Comment: So just for testing I must use a 'google for my domain' account with DKIM sign ?

Comment: Yes, or any other account that allows you to sign emails properly. This is required to prevent spoofing and bypass the whitelist.

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino I am sending email with schema to my self only using mentioned smtp setting but still same thing happening. How can I make sure it will work with gmail account

Comment: I add DKIM to my gmail domain. But mail from me to me, is not signed, so I can't test